# Alternative to MJML using Razor

Tags: razor, html-email, mjml

We have an email problem. Our system requires a front-end dev to use MJML to build a template for an email, transpile to HTML, send that to a backend dev who then has to take the HTML, figure out how to handle it (split into smaller fragments, bind data to it, using some homebrew merging code) etc. Handing the big HTML files to the backend who has to figure out what has changed, is a problem, especially for emails where we have taken the time to break the big source into smaller, more managable chunks of markup.

We were hoping to leverage something like Razor (via RazorLight) but, that does not provide the transpile capabilities that account for email/browser/responsive design.

Is there anything that can be leveraged with Razor templates? We are trying to make it so that the front end and back end devs are working with the same files in order to cut down on issues where the back end us missing things the front end has changed. Not to mention having multiple artifacts for the same deliverable.

Any ideas?

Comment: SO doesn't accept opinion based questions. You're better off asking this in a forum or discussion group or similar.

Comment: This question is a better fit for **Superuser** or **Software Recommendations**